# How to make compressed iso images?

Tags: iso-image, comparison

I have a disk image file (iso) which is about 2.5GB, but when I mount and extract it, 13GB of files comes out. It means that it strongly compressed. I have UltraIso 9.5 but, it can not compress it as is was. It can just make compressed images in (isz) format which is not a standard one.
How can I make compressed mountable iso images?

Comment: There is no standard format (on Windows) for compressed image files (that I know of). There's PowerISO's DAA and MagicISO's UIF, but they both use zlib for compression, the same as ISZ, so I doubt the sizes would be much different. (I guess the files and not the ISO were compressed originally.)

Comment: The sizes are as I say, 2,5 --> 13. I can attach some screenshots.

Comment: the UDF format supports sparse files, so you could fit a 1TB file full of zeroes in a 20kB image. This is maybe what you are seeing.